# External libraries not supporting

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-library

I am using some external libraries in my project. Earlier was working fine, but now it has stopped working.

It is showing error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.aguai.medieazy/app.aguai.medieazy.activities.MyOrders}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
                                                                    at app.aguai.medieazy.activities.MyOrders.onCreate(MyOrders.java:32)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
                                                                    at app.aguai.medieazy.activities.MyOrders.onCreate(MyOrders.java:32) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275) 
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it.neokree.materialtabs.R$styleable
                                                                    at it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost.<init>(MaterialTabHost.java:71)
                                                                    at it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost.<init>(MaterialTabHost.java:57)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
                                                                    at app.aguai.medieazy.activities.MyOrders.onCreate(MyOrders.java:32) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275) 
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error line is the`setContentView(R.layout,MYLAYOUT)` line only.

My build.gradle is:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.aguai.medieazy"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 25
        versionName "2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.5.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.5l@aar'
    compile 'com.appvirality:AppviralityUI:1.1.18+'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    /*compile 'com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:5.3.27'*/
    compile project(':gestureimageview')
   /* compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'*/

}
```

The material-tabs xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_my_orders"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/theme"
    />

<it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_my_orders"
    app:primaryColor="@color/theme"
    app:accentColor="#ffffff" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am not able to find out what went wrong.

Comment: The Problem may be in your xml file. Will your post it please ?

Comment: `Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost` show your xml

Comment: you have add more library, delete some library ya compress code . when you run app thin cross the 65K method ..

Comment: @Destro ok.. but every library is causing problem

Comment: The issue is in line number 13 in "MYLAYOUT"...What are you trying in that line?

Comment: I think "it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11" requires  some depencies..

Comment: If you are getting NoClassDefFoundError for some external jar file that you have added to the project, try adding the jar file in lib folder and add it to the classpath by Properties >> Java Build Path >> Add Variable >> Configure Variables >> New Variable Entry. And rebuild.

Comment: "compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:T'" in place of "compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11' " still not works download the library and add as module.

Comment: There's a lot of whitespace in your stack trace, which makes this harder to read. Would you edit it so that future readers may benefit from it?

Comment: Downvoted, with regrets (see above). Making questions readable for others, even after an answer has been received, is important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason, but I still don't understand it.

Earlier I was using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'`

then I update the google-play-services to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'`

So this change from 8.1 to 8.3 was causing problem.
I changed it back to 8.3, and it started working again.
Thanks a lot all of you.. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding compile project(':gifview') in your graddle file and check for correct package name in layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it.neokree.materialtabs.R$styleable
```

try to follow the instructions [MaterialTabs](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs)